# Aspect will not execute if it is in different module in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-aop

I have multiple modules like Module A, Module B and Common Module.  I have added aspect into common module. As per expression when any method contain specific annotation, it will call aspect before. But it didn't work. If I copy same aspect class and add into module (Module A) itself, it works for that module (Module A) only.  Why is it not working for common module? Do we have to do anything special to share in-between modules?

I use similar annotation which mentioned in previous question: [Multiple Audit table by using AOP and Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44755293/1930444)

```
    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class AuditAspect {

        @AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(auditable)")
        public void save(Auditing audit) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello sir, I would like to know the way to executing aspect in different modules too. Could you please share your answer..

Answer (score 1):

I followed this [link](https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/multimodule/multimodule_strategy.html) and finally it worked for me.

What I did is made some changes inside build tag in **pom.xml** for both *aspect* module and *application* module.

TestProject source code can be found [here](https://github.com/ruzalsh/MultiModule_SpringBoot_AOP)

Answer (score 0):

In module A you should specify beans from common module, smth like

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.common" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But Its already have dependency event its not working.

Comment: @NFE aven dep is no enough, you need it scanned, and this is scanning

Comment: yeah because common logic have jpa conf and other logic also and its working fine. but only aspect didn't work

Comment: Might be fail because I use generic annotation for entity. is it true. is generic works for aspect

Comment: add the code which you are trying to audit in common and A module, so we could tell where the problem is

Comment: @NFE here is a simmilar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797824/spring-aop-aspect-used-in-a-separate-module

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide full path of "Auditing" in advice as below -

```
 @AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(FULL_PATH.Auditing)")
        public void save(Auditing audit) {
 }
```